# How to share an object between functions of the same controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I work with asp MVC 4. I  have a single controller and I want to share the same object between his functions. I thought about a data member but it doesn't work. Here is my code :

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyObject obj;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        obj = new MyObject();
        this.obj.GetData();            // Fill my object
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult MyFunction()
    {
       Console.Write(this.obj);        // Always null
       return View();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to keep this object between functions ? I used to create `TempData` ou `ViewBags` for sharing data but I'm not sure if it's the right way to manage big objects.

Comment: Every time user requests page for another action controller is recreated. You may use Session for sharing variables between one user calls, and databases or caches for sharing the value between multiple users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is null because MVC framework create a new controller to handle different requests, hence the obj is also different.

If you make your Object singleton or simply make it static, it will work.

```
public static MyObject obj;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't thought about static, seems obvious now :)

Comment: Will this span different user sessions? This doesn't seem safe.

Comment: @rhuges: It's not different per user sessions. If we want to do that, we can re-write asp.net MVC IoC framework to User Sessions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        this.obj.GetData();            // Fill my object
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult MyFunction()
    {
       Console.Write(this.obj);        // Always null
       return View();
    }
}
```

This will stop your `null` error.

If you want to save data between postbacks, you will need to look into persistent data storage such as a SQL based database.

Comment: It stops my null error but obj is empty. I fix this problem with static data member (cf : @Hiệp Lê).